# Dynamic number of function arguments

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a function with dynamic number of arguments

```
example :- 
foo("a","b","c","d")
foo("a","b")
foo("a","b","c")
```

but I don't want to use array or list

Comment: You can use `varargs` in Kotlin

Comment: Or default arguments

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**vararg**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs).

Try like this

```
fun foo(vararg input: String){
    for (item in input) {
        print(item)
    }
}
foo("a","b","c","d")
foo("a","b")
foo("a","b","c")
```

**Varargs** allow users to pass in a `comma-separated` list of `arguments(data type should be same)`, which the `compiler` will `automatically wrap` into an `array`

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method like this:

```
fun foo(vararg args: String) {
    //TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vararg` keyword is used (like `...` in java) for variable number of arguments.

`vararg` also supports **spread** operator. So you can do this

`val abc = listOf("a", "b", "c")
foo("x", "y", "z", *abc, "p", "q", "r")` //x,y,z,a,b,c,p,q,r as arguments